# C :How to compare two strings and find a word i need?

Tags: c, loops, compare, strcmp

Its not complete, but in doesnt print anything

```
char *fruit[] = {"rasberry", "cherry"};
char *veg[] = {"salad", "tomato"};
char word;


printf("Print a veg or a fruit \n");
scanf("%s", &word);


for (int i = 0; i < strcmp(fruit, veg ); i++)
{
    if (word == fruit[i])
        printf("Its fruit!");
}
```

how to compare it?

Comment: What are you expecting `strcmp(fruit, veg)` to do? Did you mean to have `i < 2` (2 because there are 2 elements in `fruit`) instead?

Comment: i want that to find a word that user wrote. i ve tried to do i < 2. it didnt work

Comment: @ViktorijaKočerha: what exactly do you want? check below I posted to check if user entered fruit. You can apply same logic to check if user entered veg.

Comment: no, i want it to print what is it. a fruit or a veg

Comment: this line: char *fruit[] = {"rasberry", "cherry"}; defines a two element char *fruit[], and two literal strings rasberry and cherry.  SO to reference cherry, would be *fruit[1]  this same pattern of code needs to be followed for both the fruit and veg references

Comment: this line: char word;  word is a single character, yet the code is asking the user to input a whole word (probably several characters) into that variable.  any character after the first is corrupting the stack, which leads to undefined behaviour

Comment: this parameter in the 'for' statement: i < strcmp(fruit, veg ) will always be  i < 1 or i < -1.  this is meaningless in the current context

Comment: this line: if (word == fruit[i]) compares two pointers, which will ALWAYS be different.  it does not compare the contents of word with the contents of fruit[i].

Comment: this line: strcmp(fruit, veg ) compares the first string in fruit with the first string in veg.  a meaningless comparison, especially since those two arrays are 'preset' to different contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after a bit more clarification what is needed, try something like this:

```
    char *fruit[] = {"rasberry", "cherry"};
    char *veg[] = {"salad", "tomato"};
    char word[100]={0};


    printf("Print a veg or a fruit \n");
    scanf("%s", word);

    // Check fruit
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(word,fruit[i])==0)
        {
            printf("Its fruit \n");
        }
    }
    // Check veg
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(word,veg[i])==0)
        {
            printf("Its veg \n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: why did you do this char word[100]

Comment: @ViktorijaKočerha: because char is for storing only one character. Did you try this, it works at my side. Some more info here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html

Comment: @ViktorijaKočerha: scanf needs address of variable where it will store input - that is why you used &. But in case of arrays, the name of the array can act like the pointer, it is address of first element. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c. You can read up a bit more on c basics